# Convolution on finite interval

Tags: analysis

Convolution of two functions are usually defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$. In Laplace transformation

$f*g=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$

I want to find $D(f*g)$.

Comment: what is 'D? :d what does D mean ?

Comment: D stands for derivative with respect to t.

Answer (score 0):

oh that is easy

$$ f(t)g(0)+ \int_{0}^{t}f(\tau) \frac{g(t-\tau)}{dt} $$

Comment: Yes thats easy but I want to ask usually people use D(f*g)=f*Dg. Here, D(f*g)=f(t)g(0)+f*Dg. Kindly explain